# ¿Cómo eliminar un espacio en CSS?

Tags: html5, css, css3

Tengo un `div` con un 100% de ancho y dentro, dos `div`: uno con 85% y otro con 15% de ancho. El problema es que cuando lo veo, aparece el de 85% abajo y el de 15% aparece arriba. Uso el `float:left` para que siempre estén juntos, cuando inspecciono veo un espacio y por eso yo pienso que el `div` se va abajo. Les paso el código y la imagen, lo que necesito es que estén juntos.

Mi código:

```css
#contenedor_esquema {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #E62424;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ca-menu {
  width: 15%;
  min-width: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#formulario_esquema {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#contenedor_esquema {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #E62424;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ca-menu {
  width: 15%;
  min- width: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#formulario_esquema {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor_esquema">

  <ul class="ca-menu">
    <li class="datospersonales">
      <a href="crear_paciente.php">
        <span class="ca-icon"></span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Datos Personales</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub"></h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="esquema_tratamiento">
      <a href="crear_esquema.php">
        <span class="ca-icon"></span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Esquema de Tratamieto</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub">Ingreso de datos del tratamiento</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="ca-icon"></span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Control Clinico</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub">Ingreso de medicamentos</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="formulario_esquema">

    <form method="POST">
      <legend>Primera fase</legend>


    </form>

  </div>

</div>
```

La imagen el cuadro amarillo es el espacio que sobra y yo creo que no debería sobrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir también el HTML que hace referencia a ese CSS? Y por favor, intenta añadir un ejemplo que se pueda reproducir para que podamos ver el error. Si pulsas las teclas Cntrl+M te aparece un editor de código en el cual puedes añadir el código de tu página para mostrarlo como un ejemplo reproducible.

Comment: Podrias comentar el codigo html? para ayudarte mejor? solo la parte del error

Comment: ya lo edite con el  codigo html gracias

Answer (score 2):

El código CSS que compartes tiene varios problemas que causarán el comportamiento que explicas:

1. El mismo código CSS está repetido dos veces: esto no debería ser un problema en sí, sólo que hace tu código más difícil de depurar y mantener. Además,
2. Una de las copias tiene un fallo tipográfico: se separa `min-width` y se pone como `min- width` (esto tampoco debería ser un problema en sí, pero tampoco es bueno porque podría causar problemas si el navegador lo interpreta como `width:250px`).
3. El problema real viene con el `min-width`: si por cualquier motivo el 15% del ancho es menor que 250px (el valor del `min-width`), entonces se fuerza a que tenga un ancho mínimo de 250px. Esto hará que el `div` con ancho 85% salte a la siguiente línea. Esto quiere decir que **siempre que el `div` contenedor tengo menos de 1667px de ancho (1666.6 · 0.15 = 250), el `div` que ocupa un 85% se mostrará debajo... y como a `#contenedor_esquema` le pones un ancho máximo de 1500px, entonces el `div` del 85% SIEMPRE se mostrará debajo**.

Una posible solución es ponerle un ancho máximo al ancho del `div` del 85%. Para que sea cómo máximo 85% y que tenga por defecto un ancho del 100% menos los 250px del otro `div`. Eso se puede conseguir mediante la función `calc()` de CSS, con algo así:

```
width: calc(100% - 250px);
max-width: 85%;
```

Entonces los pasos a seguir serían:

- Limpiar el código de duplicados
- Corregir reglas incorrectas
- Añadir un máximo para el `div` grande

Con esos cambios el código se verá así y ya no se verá debajo uno del otro (aunque el `div` con un ancho del 85% nunca tendrá realmente un ancho del 85% por lo explicado arriba):

```css
#contenedor_esquema {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #E62424;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ca-menu {
  width: 15%;
  min-width: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#formulario_esquema {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  max-width: 85%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor_esquema">
  <ul class="ca-menu">
    <li class="datospersonales">
      <a href="crear_paciente.php">
        <span class="ca-icon"></span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Datos Personales</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub"></h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="esquema_tratamiento">
      <a href="crear_esquema.php">
        <span class="ca-icon"></span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Esquema de Tratamieto</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub">Ingreso de datos del tratamiento</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="ca-icon"></span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Control Clinico</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub">Ingreso de medicamentos</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="formulario_esquema">
    <form method="POST">
      <legend>Primera fase</legend>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo algo asi? es lo que necesitabas porque eso te entendi en tu pregunta y si es asi?  te sugiero que no uses ID en el css usa mejor class es mas recomendado usar class en vez de id , los id se usan en JavaScript.

El codigo corregido:

```css
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


 #contenedor_esquema
    {
         width: 100%;
         margin: 0 auto;
         overflow: hidden;
         background: #E62424;
         box-sizing: border-box;

    }

    .ca-menu{
        width: 15%;
        min-width: 250px;
        float: left;
        padding: 20px;     
        box-sizing: border-box;
         border:1px solid blue;

    }



    .formulario_esquema{
width: 100%;       
 float: left; 
        padding: 20px;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       border:1px solid blue;
       overflow: hidden;
    }

    #contenedor_esquema
    {
         width: 100%;
         max-width: 1500px;   
         margin: 0 auto;
         overflow: hidden;
         background: #E62424;
         box-sizing: border-box;

    }

    .ca-menu{
        width: 15%;
        min-

width: 250px;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;     
    box-sizing: border-box;
     border:1px solid blue;

}


#formulario_esquema{
    width: 85%; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border:1px solid blue;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenedor_esquema">

            <ul class="ca-menu">
                    <li class="datospersonales"> 
                        <a href="crear_paciente.php">
                            <span class="ca-icon"></span>
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                <h2 class="ca-main">Datos Personales</h2>
                                <h3 class="ca-sub"></h3>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="esquema_tratamiento">
                        <a href="crear_esquema.php">
                            <span class="ca-icon"></span>
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                <h2 class="ca-main">Esquema de Tratamieto</h2>
                                <h3 class="ca-sub">Ingreso de datos del tratamiento</h3>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="ca-icon"></span>
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                <h2 class="ca-main">Control Clinico</h2>
                                <h3 class="ca-sub">Ingreso de medicamentos</h3>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

     <div class="formulario_esquema">

       <form method="POST">
             <legend>Primera fase</legend>


       </form> 




     </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberías añadir un **reset CSS**, ya que los elementos tienen unas propiedades por defecto en cada navegador, como *margin* y *padding*, que pueden producir efectos indeseados como el que te esta ocurriendo, ***lo más básico*** que hay es poner al comienzo del CSS:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;

   /* Con las siguientes líneas evitaras repetirlas en cada bloque */
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Por supuesto hay soluciones más completas como [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). Yo personalmente uso una de éstas modificada: elimino los elementos que se que no voy a utilizar en cada proyecto para reducir el peso.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es tener dos columnas paralelas, un buen método es simular una tabla. Es suficiente con que a esos dos elementos les añadas la propiedad `display: table-cell`. Y por supuesto te recomiendo que evites `float` para alinear elementos. Aquí te dejo el método:

```css
#contenedor_esquema {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #E62424;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ca-menu {
display: table-cell;
  width: 15%;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#formulario_esquema {
display: table-cell;
  width: 85%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#contenedor_esquema {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #E62424;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor_esquema">

  <ul class="ca-menu">
    <li class="datospersonales">
      <a href="crear_paciente.php">
        <span class="ca-icon"></span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Datos Personales</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub"></h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="esquema_tratamiento">
      <a href="crear_esquema.php">
        <span class="ca-icon"></span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Esquema de Tratamieto</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub">Ingreso de datos del tratamiento</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="ca-icon"></span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Control Clinico</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub">Ingreso de medicamentos</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="formulario_esquema">

    <form method="POST">
      <legend>Primera fase</legend>


    </form>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Se te agradece pero responder sólo con código se considera de bajaba calidad, revisa [answer]

Comment: Pues tienes razón compañero, cuando respondí era tarde ya y estaba KO. Espero que con la edición quede más clara la respuesta.